# getting current page url of an element location when an event occurs and outputting the url on another page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a Download button the gives uses free download.

```
<input type="button" name="btn" value="Download"/>
```

Now I also have this php code that displays the current url of a page.

```
<?php
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url;
?>
```

finally I the download page... downloadbutton.php
My question is, how do I go about incorporating them together so that,
whichever website I put the download button, it echo out the current website's url where the download button is located when clicked. I want the url echoed at the downloadbutton.php

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give it this way:

```
<input type="button" name="btn" value="Download" onclick="location.href='<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>'" />
```

This redirects to the current download page.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the referer. It's a simple as this:

`echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

To redirect it's something like this:

`<input type="button" name="btn" value="Download" onlick="document.location=<? echo $url ?>">`